# How Can I Have Div Placed Outside a Container with Auto Margins and Have it Fill the Rest of the Browser Width?

Tags: html, css, percentage

I have a simple test layout here on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jJuMH/ I want the #outside div to span the width  of the browser up to the container, on the right side of the container only. I've tried floating, but that displaces the container and absolute positioning is not doing the trick either.

```
#full{
    width:100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:#0CF
    }

#container{
           width:75%;
           position:relative;
           height:300px;
           background-color:#FF9900;
           margin:0 auto;
           }
#oustide {
          width:100%;
          height:50px;
          float:right;
          background-color:#66FF66
         }


<div id="full">
<div id="oustide"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the #outside div to span the width of the browser up to the container, on the right side of the container only. I can't make sense of what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want the green top div to run the width of the container, stay the same height and display above the orange div?

Comment: What you said makes no sense to me.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I want to have the container centererd, and the green div outside the container, on the right side. I would like the green div to fill the space of the browser from the right side of the container to the right side of the browser window

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really make sense to me neither.. but why not just build your layout with fluid blocks?

```
.left, .middle, .right {
    float: left;
    min-height: 250px;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

.middle {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

quick fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jJuMH/1/

Comment: That would work yes. And it's a good idea, but it would require me to redo am entire layout. I'm just trying to add that one outside div to  an existing layout.